# Как решать задачу бинарной классификации, зная только положительные примеры?

Tags: машинное-обучение, классификация

Необходимо решить задачу бинарной классификации, но в тренировочной выборке имеются только положительные примеры. Как быть и какие методы лучше использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша задача относиться к классу задач One-Class Classification Algorithms.
Методов решения  много. В качестве введения можно посмотреть, например, вот тут:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification
https://machinelearningmastery.com/one-class-classification-algorithms/
https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~s255khan/files/occ_survey09.pdf
https://blogs.sap.com/2020/12/29/outlier-detection-with-one-class-classification-using-python-machine-learning-client-for-sap-hana/
```

В последней статье даже какая-то реализация на Python есть, хотя я сам с ней детально не разбирался.

Один из новых подходов  -  применение нейросетей типа автоенкодера. Он учиться "восстанавливать" данные на одном классе из тренировочной выборки. НА этапе использования -  он будет отлично восстанавливать данные из этого класса и существенно ошибаться при восстановлении данных не принадлежащих этому классу, что и есть признаком того, что это некоторая аномалия.